# Index of vector containing the global minimum

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdvector

Given a vector of vectors, is there an optimal way to determine the index of the vector which holds the global minimum? 
What is the complexity in Big-O notation?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

unsigned getMinimumIndex(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> const& a) {

  if (!a.size())
    return 0;

  unsigned ret = 0; unsigned temp; unsigned global = 1 << 31;
  for (std::size_t idx = 0; idx < a.size(); ++idx) {
    if ((temp = *std::min_element(std::begin(a[idx]), std::end(a[idx]))) < global) {
      global = temp;
      ret = idx;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> a = {{2, 4, 6, 8}, {3, 9, 5, 7},
                                          {3, 4, 4, 3}, {2, 8, 3, 2},
                                          {4, 4, 4, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
  std::cout << getMinimumIndex(a);  // 4-th vector posseses the value '0'
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use a `vector` of `vector`s? One contiguous `vector` and handling the 1D->2D mapping yourself will make this pretty simple.

Comment: Are your `vector`'s sorted? Because then you could probably pull off `O(log(n))` with a modified binary search. If not you'll probably be looking at `O(n)`...

Comment: @user4581301 Yes. Basically, it should have stored a custom class. I have just presented a case where possible algorithm is implemented. However, I am not sure about workarounds.

Comment: If your data is not sorted then obviously you have to scan all elements,

Comment: @scohe001 My vector is sorted, yet custom comparator is being used.

Comment: If they're sorted, then isn't the first element of each vector the lowest in that vector? I assume your global minimum is based on the same comparator.

Comment: @Barmar Not in this case. I think it's a faulty design from my side, going to rethink it. Yet it would require me to sort everything one more time.

Comment: If you have a probability statistical distribution that is not uniform,  you could "guess" a location based on this probability without sorting.

Comment: As with most optimization problems, knowing the exact _constraints_ and _requirements_ is important.  Vector-of-vectors is, more often than not, a poor choice of data structure.  It would be important to know why you use this specifically, and if there are other more practical choices that could lead to a better algorithm.  Some have mentioned ensuring the inner vectors are sorted.  Another example would be if you always guarantee a fixed number of elements in each "row", that opens up other interesting opportunities like organizing your code and data structures to suit SIMD architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Since neither your vectors nor the numbers inside a vector are **sorted**, you have to check every number to be the smallest value.
Thus you get a complexity of **O(n)**.

You can either use iterators like you did or simply use 2 for loops and access the vector with a[i][j] (which should be minor faster because of the missing overhead from iterators).

Also - since you only have unsigned int, you can break as soon as you find 0.